# Фактори-адаптер не обновляется

Tags: android, android-widgets

Хочу вывести информацию из БД в список на виджете (главного экрана). Есть фактори

```
public class WidgetFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory
{
private Cursor cursor;
private Context context;
private int widgetID;

public WidgetFactory(Context ctx, Intent intent)
{
    context = ctx;
    widgetID = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Database db = new Database(context);
    SQLiteDatabase sql = db.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = sql.query(Database.TABLE_BOOKMARKS, new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, Database.LINK, Database.TITLE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return cursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView()
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)
{
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_item_text, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.TITLE)));
    return rv;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged()
{
    cursor.requery();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{

}
}
```

Есть сервис для него

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService
{
   @Override
   public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent)
    {
         return new WidgetFactory(getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
}
```

Есть провайдер виджета

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider
{
private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
    int[] ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widget);
    for (int id : ids)
    {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        Intent adapter = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        adapter.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, id);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list, adapter);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, views);
    }
}
}
```

Список правильно отображается. Но мне нужно в активности при добавлении, редактировании и удалении записи из БД обновлять список в виджете. Пытаюсь так

```
private void updateAppWidget()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this,WidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
int[] ids = {R.id.widget_list};
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Но список не обновляется (помогает лишь повторная установка виджета). Пробовал пушить логи, обновление лишь дергает метод `onUpdate` у провайдера а в фактори не уходит. Кстати, я так понял, что обновления у фактори дергают `onDataSetChanged` там у меня обновляется курсор. Что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Вырезка из документации]

Возможно, Вам следует начать с архитектуры в целом.
Хорошие практики не только (в Android-мире), рекомендуют разделять приложение на Model-View-Contoller.

В Вашем случае необходимо иметь доступ к модели из разных view-компонентов (как activity, widgets, etc..) и, возможно, из controller-компонентов(как services)

Таким образом, официально рекомендуется использовать Content Provider, как обертка над Sqlite и модель приложения.

Правильно реализованный Content Provider избавит вас от забот о многопоточности в базе, синхронизаций различных представлений ваших данных и шаринга между приложениями.

Н-р, стандартные **CalendarWidget** или **GMailWidget** основаны на таком подходе.

*Реализация REST-клиента под Android обладает рядом особенностей. "По полочкам" все разложил, в свое время, **Virgil Dobjanschi** на Google I/O 2010, см. **"Developing Android REST client applications"** .*

- **видео:** www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE
- **слайды:** dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf
- **текст лекции:** docs.google.com/file/d/0B2dn_3573C3RdlVpU2JBWXdSb3c/edit

Comment: Отказался от виджета.. Спасибо. Потом как-нибудь возьмусь